# Retrieving a Date from 2019 in DateTimePicker leads to undesired result

Tags: c#, date, datagridview

I'm trying to enter a production date and expiry date into a `dataGridView` from a `datetimepicker`, but when i choose any date which is after 31 dec 2018, it adds the number of months to 12 and puts the total in the months result, while the year stays 2018

```
  private void button36_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
 int row = 0;
          POdataGrid.Rows.Add();
          row = POdataGrid.Rows.Count - 2;
              POdataGrid["Product_Name",row].Value = POproductNameTB.Text;
              POdataGrid["Product_Type",row].Value = POproductTypeCB.Text;
              POdataGrid["Unit_Type",row].Value = POunitTypeCB.Text;
              POdataGrid["Unit_Price", row].Value = POunitPriceTB.Text;
              POdataGrid["Quantity",row].Value = POquantityTB.Text;
              POdataGrid["Total_Price",row].Value = POtotalPrice1TB.Text;
              POdataGrid["Bonus",row].Value = PObonusTB.Text;
              POdataGrid["Sell_Price",row].Value = POsellPriceTB.Text;
              POdataGrid["Interest", row].Value = POinterestTB.Text;
              POdataGrid["Production_Date", row].Value = POpDateDP.Value.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");//POpDateDP is my first datetimepicker
  POdataGrid["Expiry_Date", row].Value = POexpDateDP.Value.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");//POexpDateDP is my second datetimepicker
}
```

Comment: Can you share what value you are selecting and what is being displayed and what is your expectations?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - it's hard to tell exactly what's going on here. I would note that `mm` in a format string means minutes rather than months though...

Comment: I just solved it, thanks every one.

Comment: I just changed it to: POdataGrid["Expiry_Date", row].value = POpExpDateDP.Value.Date; i had error in the DateTimePicker name. now it shows the exact date i choose in the data grid